# How to pass intents to open another activity with button?

Tags: android, android-intent

How to pass the intent to open another activity with button?

Comment: What do you mean? Please read this and edit your question: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I need to open another activity with an intent with out using sqlite.How to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what you are talking about. What activity? What is an "intent"? On what platform? Using what language? We don't read minds here.

Comment: Intents are the inter-process communication system used by android

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an onclicklistener on the button write something like:

```
button.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Create new activity in manifest.

Have a look at this tutorial http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/

Comment: I guess you are a mind reader. Care to explain the question?

Comment: well i think he tries to understand how to pass an intent without extras (sqlite????).

Comment: What is an "intent"? What is the context of this question?

Comment: Intent == http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: See, missing context in the question. It's an _android_ question. OP didn't tag it as such.

Comment: Yeap it is an android question.

Comment: Yes it is an android question